# Same behaviour of EM radiation at the polarisation grid and at the double slit?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, double-slit-experiment, polarization

In a diffraction grating, the EM radiation is polarised after passing through the grating, i.e. the electric and magnetic field components are aligned by the grating bars, one component parallel, the other 90° to it.

Does this polarisation also happen in a double-slit experiment?

Comment: Depends on the width of the slit.